# Which of the two LINQ Statements is would work faster?

Tags: performance, linq

1]

```
IQueryable<StronglyTypedObject> cp = 
      context.People.OfType<StronglyTypedObject>()
                    .Where(o=> o.EmployerId == Id_Method_Param_Variable);
List<StronglyTypedObject> lst = cp.ToList();
```

2]

```
List<StronglyTypedObject> cp = 
      context.People.OfType<StronglyTypedObject>()
                    .Where(o=> o.EmployerId == Id_Method_Param_Variable)
                    .ToList();
```

This may be a very simple question but I am relatively new to LINQ and would really be interested if there is a performance difference in these two executions as the number of records retrieved may be high.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0):

No, there will not be a performance reduction. I mean, you would get a **very, very, very** (in the thousandths of nanoseconds) slight reduction of speed in the first one compared to the second one as you are assigning more variables. But nothing more.

Also: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster, then **race your horses**!](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0):

In first case you create one additional variable which holds reference to query definition (thats just one additional reference on stack). Query is simple data, nothing is executed when you define query. Query will be executed when you will try to obtain it's result (e.g. call `ToList()` or iterate over query).

To understand difference between your samples consider following class:

```
public class Query
{
    private int _employeeId;

    public Query(int employeeId)
    {
        _employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    // here is query execution
    public List<Employee> ToList()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ID = " + _employeeId;
        // we execute sql query on server
        // and return employees which matches our query data            
        return listOfEmployees;
    }
}
```

Your first sample:

```
var query = new Query(42);
var result = query.ToList();
```

Your second sample:

```
var result = new Query(42).ToList();
```

The only difference is whether you store reference to query variable or not.